# crontab java process information

Tags: bash, scripts, java, cron

I try to get a bash script running that should output the java process information to a file. Unfortunately when I add it to the `crontab -e` the script is not executed.

As user `root` the script is located in /root/bin

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M`
PROCESSINFO=`ps aux | grep java | grep -v grep`

echo "$DATE $PROCESSINFO" >> java.log
```

This is the `crontab -e` configuration

```
* * * * * /root/jobs/log-crush-ftp-process.sh
* * * * * printf "test\n"
```

The `printf "test\n"` is just a test, but since the output will only go in the mail there is no result on the screen. What am I missing?

Also I have another question about Java processes. Since everything is running in a runtime enviroment, is there a command where I can get more detailed information about the processes inside the JVM?

EDIT:

I deleted the last line `printf...` and now I get mails for the script. But still no output in the `java.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a really bad issue by myself. If I did `mail` and looked the first mail with `1` then I saw the message

```
/bin/sh: /root/jobs/log-crush-ftp-process.sh: No such file or directory
```

I thought the whole time the error means the first column `/bin/sh`, but the real issue was that I renamed the `jobs` folder to `bin`. After changing the cronjob to

```
*/1 * * * * /root/bin/log-crush-ftp-process.sh
```

(*/1 for every minute) the script is now executed.